# C# Custom Shape

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

How can you make this shape in C# using DrawArc And Draw Line?
Dashed Lines Is For Description Figure.
This image should be able to rotate around the center.
MaxRange And MinRange,The center point can be changed.

[Example Shape To Draw In C# Windows Form Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8rW6.png)

For Learning And Educate To My Students

Comment: See the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921415/7444103), might be useful -- You didn't provide any specifics and you haven't posted any code that attempts to perform the drawings. You should do that

Comment: What specifically is the problem? You seem to already be aware of the drawing APIs. Just use a bit of math to convert the input parameters to the parameters for the drawing calls. It may not be your intent, but currently your question reads a bit like "Could someone do this moderately complicated task for me"?

Comment: @Saba-system I can deliver you a project that does this drawing by specifying required parameters.